# Android new Intent filters

Tags: android, android-intent

At this years Google I/O(2015), google revealed some new kind of intent filters, i don't remember the name i just remember the demo.

A google developer said something like this "Now if a person clicks on twitter link then user will be prompted to choose to open link in browser or in the twitter app but no no, this should not work like this" and he demoed a new method through which if user clicks on twitter link, it will directly open in twitter app.

I know the question is very vague but i just couldn't remember it, googling also didn't help. If anyone knows please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "deep linking".

Have a look at this topic:
http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/28/io-2015-android-m-will-support-app-deep-linking-without-that-annoying-selector-prompt/

Here is the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: Cool! Thanks for quick reply :)
Will mark your answer as correct.